# $scope.modal remains undefined on $ionicPlatform.ready

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I've been looking everywhere for an answer to this problem; I wouldn't mind but it was actually working earlier. I'm trying to open a modal in an Ionic App on load of the app if there is no user access token stored in localStorage.

This is the code I'm working with:

JS

```
.controller('LeagueCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaOauth, Spotify, Favourites) {
  $scope.favourites = Favourites.all();

  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/login.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  }).then(function (modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
    console.log($scope.modal);
  });

  $scope.openModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.show();
  };

  $scope.closeModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };

...

  $scope.loginSpotify = function () {
    $cordovaOauth.spotify('583ac6ce144e4fcb9ae9c29bf9cad5ef', ['user-read-private']).then(function(result) {
        window.localStorage.setItem('spotify-token', result.access_token);
        Spotify.setAuthToken(result.access_token);
        $scope.updateInfo();
        //$scope.closeModal();
    }, function(error) {
      console.log("Error -> " + error);
    });
  };

  $scope.updateInfo = function() {
    Spotify.getCurrentUser().then(function(data) {
      $scope.getUserPlaylists(data.id);
    }, function(error) {
      $scope.loginSpotify();
    });
  };

  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    var storedToken = window.localStorage.getItem('spotify-token');
    if (storedToken !== null) {
      Spotify.setAuthToken(storedToken);
      $scope.updateInfo();
    } else {
      $scope.openModal();
      alert('ionicPlatform ready');
    }
  });

})
```

HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>


    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ng-cordova-oauth/dist/ng-cordova-oauth.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-spotify/dist/angular-spotify.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>


    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="share">

    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-assertive">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

As I said it was actually working before, opening the modal on startup as expected. Then it just stopped working, and producing an error I'd encountered earlier for no apparent reason. The error is as follows:

```
ypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined
at Scope.$scope.openModal (http://localhost:8100/js/controllers.js:24:17)
at http://localhost:8100/js/controllers.js:60:14
at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:53329:19
at Object.ionic.Platform.ready (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:2135:9)
at Object.self.ready (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:53327:26)
at new <anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/js/controllers.js:54:18)
at invoke (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17762:17)
at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17770:27)
at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:22326:28
at self.appendViewElement (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:56883:24) <ion-nav-view name="tab-league" class="view-container tab-content" nav-view="active" nav-view-transition="ios">
```

Any help would be appreciated massively, I can't grasp what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating modal in callback function of `$ionicPlatform.ready()`.

Check this code:

```
$scope.createModal = function(){
    if($scope.modal){
        $scope.openModal();
    }
    else{
        $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/login.html', {
            scope: $scope,
            animation: 'slide-in-up'
        }).then(function (modal) {
            $scope.modal = modal;
            $scope.modal.show();
        });

        $scope.openModal = function() {
            $scope.modal.show();
        };

        $scope.closeModal = function() {
            $scope.modal.hide();
        };
    }
}
```

Call above function in place of `$scope.openModal()` in `$ionicPlatform.ready()`

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function(){
    ...
    ...
    $scope.createModal();
    ...
    ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to wrap your codes that will update `$scope` variables in `$scope.$apply()` like this:

```
$scope.$apply(function () { 
    <your codes that update $scope.<your variables>> 
});
```

It's because the codes in `$ionicPlatform.ready()` will be run in another JavaScript turn.  AngularJS doesn't know that the `$scope` variables have been updated and hence, no HTML elements will be update.

Wrapping your codes in `$scope.$apply()` will call `$scope.$digest` to apply your `$scope` variables changes to HTML.